# Find Bulk Loader jobs in SAP BODS

Tags: etl, bulk-load, sap-data-services

Is there a straight forward way to find out through the metadata whether any BODS job is using the 'Bulk Loader Option' in its target table objects.

I wanted to find all the jobs in my repository which use the Teradata Multiload option as a Bulk Loading utility.

Comment: Have you tried exporting your repository to XML (not ATL)? Try searching for a workflow that has the option enabled to see if you can find a reference of it there. You can then search through the XML (e.g. using XPath) to find other occurrences.

Comment: OK :). Searching through the XML makes a lot more sense than through ATL. I am able to find the table objects and also the bulk loading option but not the attribute that I am looking for. I need to find the values of "Errortable1" and "ErrorTable2" inside the bulk loading option. But I am not able to find this attribute in this XML somehow.

Comment: I found the teradata_errortable1 and teradata_errortable2 attributes for that table. Only one challenging thing: In BODS bulkloading option I have assigned ALIAS names (configured in the datastore) to the schema name for eg: TD_UVET.tablename, but in the XML I am not able to find the alias. Instead the actual Teradata database name comes up for eg: TDDEV.tablename. I guess I will have to make another post for that one :)..